# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'title') - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The `useLocation` of my `Article.js` gets me a `null` state, while I pass it to my `Link` component in `Home.js`. And so I have an error on `location.state.title` and `location.state.body`. Why does the `useLocation` not retrieve the state values?

Article.js (where I get my state)

```
import React from 'react';
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import './Article.css';

export default function Article() 
{

  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location);

  return (
    <div className='article-content'>
      <h2>Votre article: {location.state.title}</h2>
      <p>{location.state.body}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Home.js (where I send my state)

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Card from '../../Components/Card/Card';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {getArticles} from '../../redux/articles/articleReducer';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

export default function Home() 
{
  const {articles} = useSelector(state => (
  {
    ...state.articleReducer
  }));

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => 
  {
    if (articles.length === 0) 
    {
      dispatch(getArticles());

    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <h1 className='home-title'>Tous les articles</h1>
      <div className="container-cards">     
        {articles.map(item => 
        {
          console.log(item.title);
          console.log(item.body);
          return(
            <Card key={uuidv4()}>
              <h2>{item.title}</h2>
              <Link to={{
                  pathname: `articles/${item.title
                    .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                    .trim()}`,
                  state: {
                    title: item.title,
                    body: item.body,
                  },
                }}
              >
                Lire l'article
              </Link>
            </Card>   
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: What version of react-router-dom do you use ?

Comment: I am using version 6.

Comment: Maybe you didn't show it in the code you posted but I don't see you sending the location to the store. before retrieving it somewhere else it needs to be stored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know an alternative syntax which is working:

```
<Link 
    to={`articles/${item.title
                .replace(/\s+/g, '-')
                .trim()}`}
    state={{
        title: item.title,
        body: item.body,
    }}>
    Lire l'article
</Link>
```

However you have to understand that the location state will be empty if you refresh the page on the Article page, since the state is getting passed only if you click on the link `Lire l'article`